# dropdown menu in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

how can i style primary menu as a dropdown menu is drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would take **forever** to "Style" it, however there are tons of modules that allow it: [Nice menus](http://drupal.org/node/43047) for one...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful link on the subject without using a module like Nice menus:
http://drupal.org/node/190263

Also, make sure under site building > menus > primary links (or whatever menu you're using) you have the "expanded" option checked under the items you want to drop down.